# Internet on Ubuntu 12.04 stopped to work after installing updates from the update manager

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet, internet-connection

I have wireless Internet access and it worked well on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS until today, when I installed updates from the Update Manager. After the reloading of the computer the sign of Internet disappeared and the Internet connection stopped working.

I went to the Network section of the System settings and got such a message:

```
The system network services are not compatible with this version.
```

`ping 8.8.8.8` gives the result `Network is unreachable`.

The solution offered by drewski22785 below have solved my problem!

Thanks to everyone who gave advices!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roman,

I had the same issue, luckily I was able to figure out a fix. There appears to be an issue with the latest update of Network Manager. If you open the Ubuntu Software Center, go to History, search the keyword "Network" and you will probably see "network-manager (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4, 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.1)".

If you see this then you have the same problem as I did. The solution is to downgrade to version 3: Search in Google "ubuntu network-manager package" and select the ubuntu.com link, then scroll down the page to "network-manager-dbg" select the precise (debug) ubuntu3 version.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/network-manager-dbg

Download the 4 related packages for your system (amd64 or i386):

- network-manager (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3)

  - network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
- libnm-util2 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3)

  - network management framework (shared library)
- libnm-glib4 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3)

  - network management framework (GLib shared library)
- libnm-glib-vpn1 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3)

  - network management framework (GLib VPN shared library)

Install each of them using the command `sudo dpkg -i FILENAME`.

Restart your computer and that should fix your problem!

Comment: Thank you very much, Drewski! I did what you said and it solved my problem!

Comment: oh, +1 for you @drewski22785, I followed and got my WIFI working now.    And this is fresh brand new installation (12.04) - wifi was working during installation but after installation (and/or updates) it suddenly is not working.   After all the steps above, I used wicd to configure my WIFI.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about getting the tools working, but to get the network working as a workaround in the mean time you can try this.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or open a Terminal window and run the following command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add in here:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid enteryourssidhere
wpa-psk enteryourpassphrase
```

Save the file and close, then run the following commands in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or the Terminal:

```
sudo ifup wlan0
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

This presumes you are using private WPA/PSK.

This won't solve your long term problem but may get you connected at least.

Comment: I tried an ethernet cable to conect to internet and I have the same problem as when I try wireless.

my /etc/network/interfaces didn't help...
 and the network service is not compatible anymore with that version ...

Comment: Ping 8.8.8.8 gave new result today: Ping 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. From 169.254.8.123 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Answer (score 0):

OK, in a terminal, try the output from the commands `ip add` and `ip route`, and show us the context of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

The output from `lsmod` might also be useful.

Comment: ip add: 1: lo: LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP mtu 16436 qdisk noqueue state UNKNOWN                                               link/loopback 00.00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                      inet6 ::1/128 scope host                                 valid_lft foreverpreferred_lft forever                                                                2:eth0: BROADCAST,MULTICAST mtu 1500 qdisk noop state DOWN qlen 1000                                                                link/ether f4:6d:04:81:89:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: 3: wlan0: BROADCAST,MULTICAST mtu 1500 qdisk noop state DOWN qlen 1000         link/ether 48:5d:60:ad:1e:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: Anders, hoppas du kan hjälpa mig!

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces: auto lo iface lo inet loopback  auto eth0  iface eth0 dhcp

Comment: ip route: default dev wlan0 scope link metric 1003 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.8.123

Comment: ismod file is empty

Comment: ip addresult changed today in wlan: 3.wlan0 NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP mtu 1500 qdisk noop state DOWN qlen 1000 link/ether 48:5d:60:ad:1e:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 169.254.8.123/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link wlan0:avahi

Comment: You have a 169.254 address which means you are not getting an ip address from DHCP. Configure a static address (google for /etc/network/interfaces and you find examples)

Comment: If you do not know which ip address to configure because you are jot that familiar with your network then go to a working machine and type ipconfig /all if windows or ifconfig if Linux and adjust the ip address but keep gateway/dns and subnet the same

Comment: Roman, you should add New information to you question, so all who has tried to answer will get that information.
'lsmod' is a command. the contents of /etc/network/interfaces should only have stansa about lo, if you uses the NetworkManager.